# How to re-add owner in Google Cloud Platform when last owner made himself editor?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

In Google Cloud Platform console, the only owner accidentally made himself an editor. Now adding new members are not allowed by anyone.

Is there a way re-adding an owner?

[screenshot from Google Cloud Platform console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwIbZ.png)

Comment: Problem solved. 
All of a sudden, one of the editor got the access to add/edit roles, including making others an owner. On his console, it shows that he inherited a role as an organisation administrator (he is a Chinese user, so 機構管理員 is what it actually shows, please correct me if my translation is wrong). He is sure that he wasn't in this role before.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to use the [Admin Activity Audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/) to identify what the cause of the permission changes you describe are.